# Python Regex: Formatting use of commas, periods internationally

Tags: python, regex

I'm storing currencies in a Decimal. From the client, I could be receiving strings in the following formats:

```
US$1,000.00
€1.000,00
```

So far, I've written:

```
re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', 'US$1,000.00')
```

which will return `1000.00` (formatted the way I'd like) for the first example and `1.000` for the second (which I don't).

What would be the best way to catch both decimals correctly?

Comment: What's your expected output for `$1.000`? Or will you always have two decimal places?

Comment: If I copy paste `€1.000,00` on my ubuntu system, connected over putty, it prints `.1.000,00` (`echo €1.000,00` becomes `echo .1.000,00`, before pressing the enter key itself). Some problem with localization. Hence, first check what inputs python is receiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a module that takes care of alot of the complexities in currency formatting (in particular with respect to periods, commas and a bunch more things). The package is called `Babel`, here is a link to the particular method(s) that could help: http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/babel.numbers#babel.numbers:parse_decimal

Docs:
http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/ApiDocs/babel.numbers

Lots of other helpful internationalization utils in there.

Answer (score 2):

You could try splitting and then glueing things back together

```
import re;
z = re.split("[,.]", re.sub([^\d\.\,], '', "$1,000.00"))
''.join(z[0:-2]) + ".".join(z[-2:])  # '1000.00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a different expression for each currency. There are a lot of different currency rules and you will be in a world of hurt if you try to handle them all through a single regex. Maybe regex is the right solution here, maybe not.

Anyway, something like this would be OK:

```
money = "US$1,000.00"
decimal_rep = Decimal(0)

if money.startswith("US$"):
    decimal_rep = Decimal(re.sub(r'[^\d\.]', '', money))
elif money.startswith("€"):
    ...
```

Comment: More than what currency it is, I'm interested in getting the decimal number the client is sending. So, essentially I need something that will always return the number formatted in the following way: `1000.00` (so it can be saved to the db) whether it's being sent from the client as 1,000 or 1.000 or 1,000.00 or 1.000,00 Do you see what I'm getting at?

Comment: Yes, and that's what I meant about every currency formatting rule being different. It should be simpler to treat each case on its own, as a different regex. So you make one regex (which you already have) for US, and another for Euros. It should be the same, except with a comma instead of a period.

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import re

text = '''US$1,000.00
US$3,000,000
€1.000,00
€4.000'''
print '%s\n-------------------' % text

pat = '([$€])[ \t]*[\d,.]+'

def ripl(mat, d = dict(('$,','€.'))):
    return mat.group().replace(d[mat.group(1)],'')

print re.sub(pat,ripl,text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jordan: if there are more possible currency formats, then this is not the way to go.

However, if you know, that you'll only ever have these two formats, you can remove all non-digit characters except for periods and commas that are followed by nothing but digits:

```
output = re.sub(r'(?![.,]\d+$)\D', '', input)
```

Comment: Just posted a comment to Jordan's message about this too. I'm not too interested in the currency, because I'm saving that elsewhere. I am interested in the formatting of `.`s and `,` and making sure the expression always returns a decimal formatted like so: `1.00`